# Server upgrade PHP 5.4 - Any issues?

Tags: ee2, php, server, v2.5.5

I've just been emailed from my site host stating they will upgrade the servers to PHP 5.4.19.

We're hosting a number of sites with them and all range from EE2.2 - EE2.5.

The thing that sparked my interest, over and above due diligience, was these comments:

> - Safe mode is no longer supported. Any applications that rely on safe mode may need adjustment, in terms of security.
> - Magic quotes has been removed. Applications relying on this feature may need to be updated, to avoid security issues.
>     get_magic_quotes_gpc() and get_magic_quotes_runtime() now always
>     return FALSE. set_magic_quotes_runtime() raises an E_CORE_ERROR level
>     error.
> - The register_globals and register_long_arrays php.ini directives have been removed.

Does anyone know if I should be on the look out for issues with the sites we're hosting here or should it be plain sailing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've EE  site (from version 2.3 till 2.6.1) running on PHP5.4, no problem.

Francois

Comment: Thx lads, worfoual could do with the rep though so I gave him the vote

Answer (score 1):

Those PHP features were deprecated long ago, EE core is certainly not using them. You may however run into issues with add-ons, especially on older sites running EE 2.2.

On your up to date versions though you should be fine. I know a large number of EE sites are using PHP 5.4 these days with no issues.